# hook_node_validate doesn't work

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I have a new type of content **project**.

I allowed an anonymous user to add project content in /node/add/project.

I want to add a test before saving node (like the **hook_form_validate** of webform)

I use **hook_node_validate** but it's not working

```
function projects_node_validate($node, $form)
{ 
  die 'in hook';
}
```

If this is the right hook, how can I use it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work fine as long as your module name is "projects"

Did you clear all the site caches after adding the code. Drupal won't detect and start using that hook until you have

Comment: yes I did, and my custom module name is "projects". but doesn't work!

Comment: And your module is definitely enabled in the module listing screen?

Comment: Isn't `hook_node_validate` only for modules that provide a node type through `hook_node_info`? And only specifically for that type? Usually you would use `hook_form_alter` to validate an entity form of any type

Comment: Dont believe so, I've just tried in an empty .module and its working fine

Comment: I cleared my site cache many times. finally I tried with an other browser and it's ok! Thank you very much @LeighMason.